# mysql procedure integer to string error

Tags: codeigniter, stored-procedures, mysqli, integer

I have an `INSERT` query in mysql.

I use `procedure` and my query is this: (I use codeigniter framework)

```
$query = $this->db->query('call Set_Shoe_SP(1, NULL, ?)' , array($type) );
```

`$type` is an integer, but it wants to insert as a `string`, and this error occurs:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
call Set_Shoe_SP(1, NULL, '20',
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\royalshop\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a data type error then it's as simple as casting the data type to string like this

```
Array((string)$type)
```

Not sure that this is your error

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
$query = $this->db->query('call Set_Shoe_SP(1, NULL, ' . $type . ')' , FALSE );
```